# iOS SecPKCS12Import parameter value

Tags: ios, iphone, single-sign-on, keychain

We have an SSO certificate pushed by the MDM installed on our iOS device. We are required to use that certificate to implement SSO by passing it to our authentication service. Based on this note from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1745/_index.html

It says we must import the certificate from system keychain into the app keychain using `SecPKCS12Import`. The first parameter to this function is `pkcs12_data`. I have read the documentation and looked through forums but cannot comprehend how to get the data for the SSO certificate that I am trying to import. Can someone please help out on how to retrieve the data value that can be passed to `SecPKCS12Import`?

Thanks.

Comment: Also posted this question on Apple developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/147590#147590

Comment: Answer is posted on Apple's forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/147590